# In jQuery How to Call a Function When Images Loaded In a "Each & Load" Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a little plugin like this:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.extend({
    myplugin: function (callback) {
      return this.each(function(){
        $(this).one('load',function(){
          // Manipulate Images
        }) ;
      }) ;
    }
  }) ;
})(jQuery);
```

I want to fire a callback after plugin finishes its job:

```
jQuery('img').myplugin({function(){
  // Do something
}) ;
```

How can I do this?

**Edit:** It is still not solved, even I got a minus point because of my question found not clearly specified. But it must be obviously a little bit tricky solution. Are there any js ninja who can solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use deferred objects:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.extend({
        myplugin: function (callback) {

            // create array of deferred objects to track loading
            var dfds = this.map(function(ix, el) {
                return $.Deferred(function(def) {
                    $(el).one('load', def.resolve)
                         .one('error', def.resolve);
                }).promise();
            }).get();

            // register the final callback
            $.when.apply($, dfds).done(callback);

            // and chain
            return this;
        }
    }) ;
})(jQuery) ;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Yq4Mf/1/  (thanks @salexch for the initial fiddle which I've then forked with my answer)

Comment: @salexch the problem with that version is that it'll fire the alert as soon as _any_ image fails, rather than waiting for every image to do its thing.  That's why my version above uses `.resolve` both for success and failure.

Comment: @salexch  and that's why it's wrong - `$.when()` will fire immediately there's any `.reject` in its list, and not wait for any other outstanding deferred items to be resolved.  p.s. there's no need to wrap `task.resolve` in a closure, you can pass it directly as a callback.

Comment: Wow Thank you!! Thats script has many features that I dont know! What does "this.resolve" mean? Can I replace my image manipulation function with it?

Comment: @Digerkam `.resolve` is used to "complete" the promise that a deferred object returns.  (A deferred object returns a "promise" to return something later, instead of returning a value now).  You can put a different function there, but make sure you call `def.resolve()` at the end of that function.  NB: I've added the `def` parameter to `$.Deferred()` and changed `this` to `def` so you can do that.

Comment: Could you share an example for custom function? Sorry I didnt get where I should put my function that handle each image..

Comment: I never used deffered helpers before, but I prepared this: http://jsfiddle.net/akkara/wZCJY/2/ looks work fine, what is your opinion about it? does "when" work with job array also? Thank you!

Comment: @Digerkam see http://jsfiddle.net/Yq4Mf/2/ for example including image handling.  What do you mean by "job" array?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution would be

```
 var cnt = 0;    
 (function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        myplugin: function (callback) {
            cnt = this.length;
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).one('load',function(){
                    // Manipulate Images

                    // Fire callback
                    if (--cnt==0) callback();
                }).error(function(){
                   if (--cnt==0) callback();
                }) ;
            }) ;
        }
    }) ;
})(jQuery) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        myplugin: function (callback) {
            this.each(function(){
                $(this).one('load', function() {
                    // Manipulate Images
                }) ;
            });
            callback();
            return this;
        }
    }) ;
})(jQuery);
```

Edit: Reverted. Your question is not very clearly specified...

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood your question. You mean a callback when all images have loaded? Let me edit...

Comment: Now this is my answer... Except you added two bugs.

Comment: What does `count == count--;` do?

Comment: @Blender It does nothing. And `count = count--` wouldn't fix it.

Comment: What if a image couldnt load?

Comment: @Cecchi As I precised, `count = count--;` doesn't change `count`.

Comment: @dystroy, good catch. Thanks. Didn't see your answer when I wrote mine.

Comment: It looks not nice, how about write it only "if (--count)" :)

Comment: You fire callback immidiately, but images wouldnt loaded

Answer (score 0):

A solution :

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        myplugin: function (callback) {
            var nb = this.length;
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).one('load',function(){
                    // Manipulate Images
                    if (--nb==0) callback();
                }) ;
            }) ;
        }
    }) ;
})(jQuery) ;
```

Comment: What if a image couldnt load?

Comment: Then the callback isn't called. Isn't it your requirement ? It sounds reasonable.

Comment: I need to fire it whether loaded or not

Comment: In that case, simply add a call to `callback` immediately following the `each` loop and return a value (probably `this`) after that. Your question could use a little more clarification.

Comment: Sorry! But I said as "plugin finishes its job" not when plugin "return", it is asynchronous loading..